# Two dice are rolled. If the sum is greater than 8, what is the probability that it is 11?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Two dice are rolled. If the sum is greater than 8, what is the probability that it is 11?

I'm not sure if this question is asking for conditional probability or just 2/10...

Comment: Both $\mathbb{}\mathbb{}$

Comment: Yes, it's a conditional probability: if the sum is $X$ then you want $P(X = 11 | X > 8) = P(X = 11 \cap X > 8) / P(X > 8) = P(X = 11) / P(X > 8)$.